# Scrapy parsing of the hidden information appearing after link click

Tags: javascript, parsing, attributes, scrapy, hidden

I try to parse some hidden information:

```
<a id="showInfoBtn" rel="nofollow" title="SomeTitle" href="some_link/some_hash"
onclick="return showInfo(event)">Info showed here after click</a>
```

When I manually click to this link, only get request to http://www.google-analytics.com appears at the firebug. And page not reloaded - only info showed as a link text.

How can I get info by scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand very well if what you're trying to get is to show some info inside the `a` tag or in other part of the page. But in any of the cases that will also depend on what does the `showInfo()` function return.

If the first case is what you need and `showInfo()` returns the text with the info, i believe this is what you're looking for:

```
<a id="showInfoBtn" rel="nofollow" title="SomeTitle" href="#" onclick="this.innerHTML=showInfo(event)">
    Info showed here after click
</a>
```

Here's a demo with the example http://jsfiddle.net/P49Dv/ ;)

Comment: Yes, info appeared at link text. This is not my page. I scrape it with http://scrapy.readthedocs.org                               `def parse_page(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    # How to parse hidden_link_text here`